# using xpath go to next page with scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I create a spider to scrape data from a website. It was ok until I added a crawlspider with rule to keep it continue with next pages. I guess that my xpath in Rule is wrong. Could you please help me to fix it? Ps: I'm using python3

This is my spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Spider, CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from task11.items import Digi

class tutorial(CrawlSpider):
    name = "task11"
    allowed_domains = ["meetings.intherooms.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://meetings.intherooms.com/meetings/aa/al"]

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('(//a[@class="prevNext" and contains(text(),"Next")])[1]')),callback="parse_page", follow=True),)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//*[@class="all-meetings"]/tr')
        items = []

        for site in sites[1:]:
            item = Digi()
            item['meeting_title'] = site.xpath('td/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

And this is my expect result which I have got after scaping the first page (and want to get more from next pages):

```
2018-08-30 08:59:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://meetings.intherooms.com/meetings/aa/al>
{'meeting_title': ['Alabama Avenue & Lauderdale Street',
                   'SELMA,  ',
                   'TUESDAY',
                   '7:00 PM',
                   'Alcoholics Anonymous']}
2018-08-30 08:59:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://meetings.intherooms.com/meetings/aa/al>
{'meeting_title': ['Alabama Avenue & Lauderdale Street',
                   'SELMA,  ',
                   'THURSDAY',
                   '7:00 PM',
                   'Alcoholics Anonymous']}
2018-08-30 08:59:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://meetings.intherooms.com/meetings/aa/al>
{'meeting_title': ['Alabama Avenue & Lauderdale Street',
                   'SELMA,  ',
                   'SUNDAY',
                   '7:00 PM',
                   'Alcoholics Anonymous']}
2018-08-30 08:59:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://meetings.intherooms.com/meetings/aa/al>
{'meeting_title': ['210 Lauderdale Street',
                   'SELMA,  36703',
                   'MONDAY',
                   '6:00 PM',
                   'Alcoholics Anonymous']}
```

Comment: Shouldn’t be @href instead of text() ??

Comment: @ Andrés Pérez-Albela H. : I tried to change into @href but it still not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this for `restrict_xpaths` (not a link's text or href but link node itself):

```
restrict_xpaths='(//a[@class="prevNext" and contains(text(),"Next")])[1]'
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! it works perfectly now. I also had 2 other mistakes: set follow as "False" in Rule; and (very silly mistake) wrote Spider instead of CrawlSpider. I aleady update the final version in my Questio. Once again, thank you a lot for your help!!!!!! Sorry, I do not have enough reputation to vote your answer :(

Answer (score 0):

I would use the class of the Next Page button:

```
response.xpath('//a[@class="prevNext"]/@href')
```

Which results in 2 results. One for top and one for button arrow. 
But when you open the first next page (2nd page), the previous page gets a link with class prevNext as well. 
This isn't a big issue because scrapy would filter most of the additional requests. 
But it's possible to restrict the links with a text filter:

```
response.xpath('//a[contains(text(),"Next")]/@href')
```

Or if you have doubts that Next is in other links as well you can combine them:

```
response.xpath('//a[@class="prevNext" and contains(text(),"Next")]/@href')
```

Comment: Thank you,Thomas; but, unfortunately, I doesn't work to me. Let I show you 1 line in my result which I already scraped from first page (and trying to continue from next pages: 
https://meetings.intherooms.com/meetings/aa/al>
{'meeting_title': ['Alabama Avenue & Lauderdale Street',
                   'SELMA,  ',
                   'TUESDAY',
                   '7:00 PM',
                   'Alcoholics Anonymous']}

Comment: You asked if the xpath for the next page is correct or not, and it was not correct. Including it into the loop so it works correctly can be done by yourself ... probably check https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-crawl-a-web-page-with-scrapy-and-python-3